# How do you close all Tkinter windows when specific window closes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, logic

I have this application in Python Tkinter. There is a Python file which is a main menu. When I click an option in the main menu it imports a python file with code that makes a new window (couldn't use `Toplevel` for the new window for some reasons). So when I close the main menu it should close all the other windows.

Here is my code for the main menu:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")


def newWindowImport():
    import file1

def newWindowImport2():
    import file2


newWindow = Button(text="new window", command=newWindowImport).pack()
newWindow2 = Button(text="new window", command=newWindowImport2).pack()


# Here is there a way so that when I exit it destroys the Main Menu as well as the opened windows
exitBtn = Button(text="Exit", command=root.destroy())


root.mainloop()
```

I tried the `root.destroy` method but it only destroys the main menu and not all the windows. Is there a way so that when I exit the main menu it destroys the main menu as well as the opened windows? If I were to use `Toplevel` - how would I use it in a separate file?

Comment: Please edit your question and include an example of what's in these imported files — to give folks a clue as to why using a `Toplevel `didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your other scripts have individual instances of `Tk()`, their own `mainloop()` and are not under a function, if that is the case, you can have all the code in your files under a function and use `Toplevel()`, example, `file1` should look like

```py
def something():
    window=Toplevel()
    #Rest of the code
```

And similarly `file2`, after that in your main program you could do something like this

```py
from tkinter import *
import file1, file2

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")

def newWindowImport():
    file1.something()

def newWindowImport2():
    file2.something()

newWindow = Button(text="new window", command=newWindowImport)
newWindow.pack()
newWindow2 = Button(text="new window", command=newWindowImport2)
newWindow2.pack()

# Here is there a way so that when I exit it destroys the Main Menu as well as the opened windows
exitBtn = Button(text="Exit", command=root.destroy)

root.mainloop()
```

You could also let go of the functions and make these changes to have it shorter

```py
newWindow = Button(text="new window", command=file1.something)
newWindow.pack()
newWindow2 = Button(text="new window", command=file2.something)
newWindow2.pack()
```

The reason for your approach not working would be that each file had it's own `mainloop()` and hence they couldn't  be destroyed when you called `root.destroy` in the main code.

Also note that I have removed the parentheses `()` from the `command=root.destroy` otherwise the it will be called as soon as the program initializes.

**EDIT :** As also suggested by @martineau in the comments, it's better to use `.pack()` on the `Button` instances separately as it provides more flexibility in using the instance later in the program, as opposed to having them hold the value `None` which is the return from `.pack()`

Comment: `pack()` always returns None, so that's the value being assigned to `newWindow` and `newWindow 2`.

Comment: @martineau I agree to that but if OP doesn't want to make any changes to the `Button`'s configurations in the future, I don't think that should be a problem, please correct me if I'm wrong, I'd be glad to learn

Comment: While it may be true you've getting away with the doing it in the example code and may even know it, that's certainly not obvious. Since it's a such common newbie mistake, I think it it would be best not to reinforce the potential problem by repeating it (twice!).

Comment: @martineau thank you for your suggestions, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Toplevel`](https://web.archive.org/web/20200121125455id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) is the correct way to do this, you need to find out why that is not working and correct it. If you did that this question would solve itself. Also, you need to remove the () from the command, it should be like this:

```
exitBtn = Button(text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
```

Comment: While I agree that using `Toplevel` would be the ideal way to do it, the OP specifically says they tried using it and it didn't work.