# Can a tkinter button's command execute root.mainloop() from another gui?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a `tkinter` python script, containing a second imported tkinter python script,

What I want to do is to run the `root.mainloop()` of the second tkinter python script which has been all imported, by clicking a button made in the first tkinter python script.

It is going to be implemented like this :

```
Button(root, command = Second GUI's root.mainloop())
```

Is this possible to be achieved ? if not, are there any alternatives available to open a 2nd GUI Window from a button created in the 1st GUI python script ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65526427/14094985) answer your question? I believe it's very similar to your requirement.

Comment: Have you tried it to see what would happen?

Comment: first try and ask question when you get error message.

Comment: in second script keep code in function and then you can `import other_file` and assign function to button `command=other_file.function`. But `tkinter` doesn't like to run two `mainloop` and two `Tk()` - it may not run both GUIs at the same time. You may need to use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` to create second window - and then you don't have to run second `mainloop` for this.

Comment: actually what i did was create a new script with a single function in it that contains the whole structure layout, then i imported that script into the main script(parent) and call the function in the child script with lambda. It works as what i would like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to import it to your main script and then call the function from there.

Comment: Did exactly what you told me to do, and it does work. Thank You so much for the help @Liv

Comment: No problem mate, would appreciate your thumbs up on my answer :)